# Nginx location doesnt cath php files

Tags: nginx

Hello i hope someone can help me because i tried every configuration possible. I looked around the internet a lot and there were many variations of how to use location block to prevent someone from accessing php files and none of them worked... Finally i found this:

```
server {

server_name mywebsite.com   www.mywebsite.com;


access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.access.log rt_cache;
error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com.error.log;


root /var/www/mywebsite.com/htdocs;



index index.php index.html index.htm;


include common/wpfc-php7.conf;

include common/wpcommon-php7.conf;
include common/locations-php7.conf;
include /var/www/mywebsite.com/conf/nginx/*.conf;

limit_req zone=one burst=8;
limit_conn two 2;

    location ~ (.php|.aspx|.asp|myadmin|wp-includes|wp-content) {
            return 301;
    }

    location ~ /(wp-admin|wp-login) {
            allow my.ip;
            limit_req zone=one burst=50;
            deny all;
    }
    location = /xmlrpc.php {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Now this code works like it should. If i try to access aspx,asp on ANY folder i get 301 if i try to access ANYTHING in wp-includes,wp-content i get 301 HOWEVER if i try to access php i get 404. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post the complete `server` block.

Comment: Posted a complete server block @MichaelHampton

Comment: With Nginx caching you need to make sure the headers sent by the PHP app are correct, or rewrite them in Nginx if required. Reference [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/). That's not your current problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all files with extensions like `.php`, `.asp`, `.aspx` you can try regular expression line this `((.*).php|(.*).aspx|(.*).asp|myadmin|wp-includes|wp-content)` into your location. See example on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ub7EIU/1/).

So your location should look like this:

```
location ~ ((.*).php|(.*).aspx|(.*).asp|myadmin|wp-includes|wp-content) {
    return 301;
}
```

another place to check code is

https://nginx.viraptor.info/ with full condif

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  example.com;

 location ~ ((.*).php|(.*).aspx|(.*).asp|myadmin|wp-includes|wp-content) {
   return 301;
 }
}
```

and tested url http://example.com/something.php

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer however code block shown in my post at least catches asp and aspx requests, your code doesnt work AT ALL :/

Comment: It's interesting:) I've checked your full conf at https://nginx.viraptor.info/ for url like http://mywebsite.com/something.php and got as result matching to location suggested by me. Can you specify which part of the code doesn't work.

Comment: I copied the server block to nginx.viraptor.info and tried url http://www.mywebsite.com/images/asda.php that worked... However on my website it doesnt... it catches asp aspx file request, wp-includes,wp-content but NOT php files... i seriously dont get it why is this happening

Comment: Can you add to your post another included *.conf files (common/wpfc-php7.conf, common/wpcommon-php7.conf and others)? Maybe answer is there

Comment: Im not a very brith person :D in wpfc-php7.conf i found this.. location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php7;
  fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
  fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
  fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
}
That makes sense now why i get 404. Question is.. what if i delete this block ?

Comment: Just try to comment these lines:) If you want to get 301 for all urls ending on .php

Comment: Well that worked.... i get 301 but... my entire website doesnt work..I guess i should just leave it as is because that configuration already returns 404. I get a lot of requests to random locations on my website to various non existing php files. So i just wandered if i can make sure that even if someone manages to hit php file that does exist on my wordpress website they would still get 404 but that might not be possible.